# Жирный шрифт в Safari на MacOS

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

На сайте текст  выглядит жирным в Safari на MacOS.
Можно ли это побороть? И если нельзя, то как аргументировать это заказчику?т

Comment: 5 вопросов, 0% принятых. К успеху идем.

Comment: Не понял. Это сарказм был?

Comment: Не обращал раньше на это внимания, спасибо что сказали. А по теме есть ответ?

Comment: А вы указываете шрифт явно? Может быть, этого шрифта на макоси нету, и она подставляет шрифт по умолчанию? Попробуйте указать хороший fallback, например, как здесь: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp (подберите шрифт, который точно есть на макоси)

Comment: Загляните ещё сюда: www.codestyle.org/servlets/FontStack

Comment: >> Не понял. Это сарказм был?

Да. Теперь все хорошо :)

Comment: VladD, спасибо, но я уже пользуюсь этими шрифтовыми стэками. Так что с этим проблем не должно быть. А у вас не было такой проблемы или вы не смотрели?

Comment: Сайт-то какой? Шрифты какие?

Answer (score 3):

Если используются системные шрифты, то эта проблема решается с помощью CSS:

```
.element-selector {
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

MacOS понимает это значение и делает шрифты тонкими, а Windows воспринимает это свойство как `normal`.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, решается при помощи `-webkit-font-smoothing`.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/122269/

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте подключить Google Web Fonts (http://www.google.com/webfonts)  к сайту - так шрифты будут у всех загружаться гарантированно те, что нужно.